# Criar campos dinamicamente em js

Tags: html, jquery

Estou a criar um select dinamicamente em jquery. Quando crio o select, faço uma consulta a uma tabela da base de dados para carregar os valores no select.

Carrega os valores corretamente, mas existe um problema. Vou colocar um exemplo do meu código.

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];

var campos_max = 10; 

var x = 0;
$('#add_field').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

 if (x < campos_max) {
    $('#listas').append('<select class="form-control1 Reff" name="Ref[]"></select>');
 
}

var html = $('.Reff').html("");

cars.forEach(element => {
  html += `<option value="`+element.colour+`">`+element.colour+`</option>`;
    });
    
    $('.Reff').html(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```

O problema é que crio o primeiro select e seleciono um valor. Depois quando crio outro select no botão retira o valor que selecionei no select anterior e não devia.

Só devia retornar a consulta vinda da base dados no select que estou a criar e não alterar o anterior.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Alterei a minha pergunta de forma a ser mais fácil de perceber o meu problema. Também criei um exemplo com o problema que estou a enfrentar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que isto resolva seu problema, toda vez ele recriava todos os `select`, usei template string para adicionar a variavel `x` como classe de identificação para cada select assim apenas adiciono um novo sem recriar os anteriores.

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];

var campos_max = 10; 

var x = 0;
$('#add_field').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 

 if (x < campos_max) {
    $('#listas').append(`<select class="form-control1 Reff reff${x}" name="Ref[]"></select>`);
 
}

var html = $(`.reff${x}`);

cars.forEach(element => {
  html.append(`<option value="`+element.colour+`">`+element.colour+`</option>`);
    });
    
    //$('.Reff').html(html);
    x++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```

Comment: poderá dar um voto positivo na minha pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Em resumo o algoritmo de seu exemplo diz que:

> Para todo clique do botão cujo o atributo `id="add_field"`:
>
> 1. Cancela a ação padrão do evento.
> 2. Confira se `x` é menor que `campos_max`
>
>    - se for menor crie e componha textualmente um elemento `<select>` e o adicione ao elemento cujo o `id` é `listas`.
> 3. Para **todos** elementos da página cujo a classe seja `Reff` apague o seu conteúdo `html("")` e retorna o conteúdo em *html* na
>    variável `html` do primeiro elemento da página cujo a classe seja
>    `Reff`.
> 4. Para cada elemento do array `cars`
>
>    - crie e componha textualmente um elemento `<option>` e com  valor do elemento.
>    - concatene a representação textual desse elemento `<option>` ao conteúdo da variável `html`.
> 5. Para **todos** elementos da página cujo a classe seja `Reff` substitua seu conteúdo pelo conteúdo da variável `html`.

É possível se observar que:

- Não se justifica esse cancelamento da ação padrão do evento `click` já que o elemento `<button>` cujo o atributo `type="button"` [não possui comportamento padrão](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).
- A variável `x` sempre terá o valor `0` no seu código tornando inútil a tentativa em limitar o número de elementos criados.
- Todos os elementos `<selects>` possuem os mesmos atributos.
- O código reiteradamente faz alterações indiscriminadas nos elementos da página cujo a classe seja `Reff` não diferenciando um elemento já estabelecido de um recém criado.

Não é possível se observar se:

- a variável `cars` sofrerá ou não alteração de conteúdo em tempo de execução impedindo determinar se o conjunto de elementos `<options>` serão sempre os mesmos ou se alterarão durante o funcionamento do programa. Impedindo a sugestões de optimização.

Proponho com base nas constatações acima a modificação do algoritmo.

Para todo clique do botão cujo o o atributo `id="add_field"`:

> 1. Confira se a variável `x` é maior ou igual a constante `campos_max`
>
>    - se maior abandona a função.
> 2. Crie e componha um elemento `<select>`, guarde sua referência na variável `select`.
> 3. Para cada elemento do array `cars`
>
>    - Crie e componha textualmente um elemento `<option>` e o adicione ao elemento `<select>` recém criado.
> 4. Adicione adicione pela referência o recém criado elemento `<select>` ao elemento cujo o `id` é `listas`.
> 5. Incremente a variável `x`.

**Implementação do algoritmo acima utilizando o DOM:**

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];


const campos_max = 10;

let x = 0;
$('#add_field').click(function(e) {
  if (x >= campos_max) return;
  const select = document.createElement("select");
  select.classList.add("form-control1", "Reff");
  select.name = "Ref[]";
  cars.forEach(element => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerText = element.colour;
    option.value = element.colour;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  $("#listas").append(select);
  x++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```

**Implementação do algoritmo acima fazendo a construção de textual de elementos HTML:**

```js
var cars = [
   {colour: "red", },
   {colour: "white", },
   {colour: "black", },
];


const campos_max = 10;

let x = 0;
$('#add_field').click(function(e) {
  if (x >= campos_max) return;
  const select = $($.parseHTML('<select class="form-control1 Reff" name="Ref[]"></select>'))[0];  
  cars.forEach(element => {
    const option = $($.parseHTML(`<option value="`+element.colour+`">`+element.colour+`</option>`))[0];
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  $("#listas").append(select);
  x++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listas"></div>

<button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-warning caixa"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>
```